# What does the clojure syntax '[] mean?

Tags: clojure

`'()` is a syntax sugar for `(quote ())`. But what does `'[]` mean? Quote a vector?

For example:

```
(use '[clojure.test :as t])

(.get '[a b c] 1)

(.containsAll '[a b c] '[b c])

((fnth 5) '[a b c d e])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Precisely. `'` is a synonym for `quote`, so

```clj
'[a b c]
```

is just

```clj
(quote [a b c])
```

[`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) prevents evaluation of a Clojure code, so quoting the whole vector is essentially the same as quoting every single element of it:

```clj
['a 'b 'c]
```

It allows you to produce a vector of [symbols](http://clojure.org/reader#toc1), without explicitly calling [`symbol` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/symbol):

```clj
[(symbol "a") (symbol "b") (symbol "c")]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! `user> (= '[a b c] ['a 'b 'c] [(symbol "a") (symbol "b") (symbol "c")])
true`